# PHP SOAP web service non-wsdl mode not working, "Could not connect to host"

Tags: php, web-services, soap

I'm trying to make a simple PHP web service that returns a simple message. I have enabled SOAP in php.ini. I'm getting the following error:

```
SoapFault exception:
    [HTTP] Could not connect to host in D:\AppServ\www\projectName\SOAPWSTest\client.php:11
Stack trace:
    #0 [internal function]: SoapClient->__doRequest('__soapCall('flag', Array)
    #2 {main}string(494) " "
```

Line 11 corresponds to the [`__soapCall`](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php). [`__getLastRequest`](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.getlastrequest.php) returns nothing. I tried setting [`soap_version`](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php) to `SOAP_1_2` or `SOAP_1_1` to no avail. I have to set `connection_timeout` to `1` because if not, the browser takes forever to do a timeout and return the same message. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Firewalls and whatnot are probably not a problem, as other parts of the project work perfectly.

One of my guesses would be that the namespace is wrong, but I haven't found a good and simple explanation of how the namespace works. Also, all simple web service examples I have tried implementing give me the same problem, which leads me to think this is some kind of configuration problem.

Codes are as follows:

**Server:**

```
<?php
function flag(){
    return "<img src='http://usa.fmcdn.net/data/flags/w580/ga.png' alt='Georgia'>";
}
$server = new SoapServer(null, array('uri' => "http://localhost:81/projectName/SOAPWSTest/"));
$server->addFunction('flag');
$server->handle();
```

**Client:**

```
<?php
print "<h1>SOAP Client</h1>";
print "<h2>Echo Web Service</h2>";
$client = new SoapClient(null, array(
    'connection_timeout' => 1,
    'trace' => TRUE,
    'exceptions' => FALSE,
    'location' => "http://localhost:81/projectName/SOAPWSTest/server.php",
    'uri'      => "http://localhost:81/projectName/SOAPWSTest/"
    ));
print $client->__soapCall("flag", array(null));
print "</br></br>Last request:</br></br>" . var_dump($client->__getLastRequest());
```